# error while creating a new environment anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

Yesterday and today I don't understand what's happening, my anaconda has been installed for 4 years. I have been creating environment to test several things separately.

here is the full error stack

```
(base) conda create -n new_env python=3 pip=22 -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 281, in _load
        repodata_fn=self.repodata_fn)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 670, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        raise Response304ContentUnchanged()
    conda.core.subdir_data.Response304ContentUnchanged
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1129, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 86, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 93, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 72, in wrapper
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 43, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 159, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 200, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 304, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 86, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 467, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1062, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 302, in get_reduced_index
        repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 137, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 130, in <lambda>
        package_ref_or_match_spec))
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 142, in query
        self.load()
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 207, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 296, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 344, in _read_local_repdata
        _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 382, in _process_raw_repodata_str
        json_obj = json.loads(raw_repodata_str or '{}')
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 193500 column 9 (char 6291456)

`$ /home/user1/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n llama python=3 pip=22 -y`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user1/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/user1/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                     PATH=/home/user1/anaconda3/bin:/home/user1/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lo
                          cal/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:/h
                          ome/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/user1/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/user1/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : 3.22.0
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.7=0
                          __linux=4.18.0=0
                          __glibc=2.28=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/user1/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/user1/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/user1/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/user1/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/user1/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/user1/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64 rocky/8.6 glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 1027:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload successful.

What is creating such bug!!! I really don't understand! Can you help me?